# Laravel 5 Unusual Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Seeting up a laravel 5 project, in which I have an unusual relationship to create.

the model Foo connects to exactly two instances of the model Bar (under different keys), but each Bar can only connect to a single Foo, regardless of which of the two fields it is occupying. i.e.

```
Foo
  id
  barA()
  barB()
Bar
  id
  foo()
```

Not sure how to properly map this in terms of relationships. I've tried

```
Foo{
   public function barA(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Bar','bar_a_id');
   }
   public function barB(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Bar','bar_b_id');
   }
}
```

Which works reasonably well, but there I can't figure out how to create the flipside of the relationship.

I know I could use a 1:m relationship, but then it becomes ambiguous which entity is 'a' and which is 'b'.

anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about this would be to use a One-To-Many relation and use model observers to enforce the limitations.

As for identifying a and b is there something else in the object you can identify these by? You could always store a column on the model itself and use a scope to pull the correct one out. So you'd end up with something like `$foo->bar()->a()->first()` and `$foo->bar()->b()->first()`

I would avoid using the 2 column approach like in your question. Done that on an older project, its horrid.

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice. I'll try to make it work as a 1:m relationship.